# Cast result of hibernate query to DTO

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a problem when cast result of hibernate query to class DTO. My database, code and bug here:
**database**

> I count and sum all mistake and achievement and get result to jsp file
>   [Table name: record, type 0 is mistake, type 1 is achievement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBeMI.png)

**Result of query in phpmyadmin**

```
|---------------------------------------------------|
|StaffId  |  achievement   |   mistake   |   total  |
|   1111  |    0           |       2     |    -2    |
|---------------------------------------------------|
```

**Repository**

```
@Override
public List<RecordFormHomePage> selectt() {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List<RecordFormHomePage> recordsList = (List<RecordFormHomePage>)session.createSQLQuery(
            "select `StaffId`,sum(case when `Type`=1 then 1 else 0 end) as achievement, sum(case when `Type`=0 then 1 else 0 end) as mistake, sum(case when `Type`=1 then 1 else 0 end)-sum(case when `Type`=0 then 1 else 0 end) as total from Records group by `StaffId`\n"
                    + "").setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(RecordFormHomePage.class)).list();
    System.out.println(recordsList.size());
    return recordsList;
}
```

**Service**

```
@Override
public List<RecordFormHomePage> list() {
    List<RecordFormHomePage> list = recordRepository.selectt();
    return list;

}
```

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping
public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("TopStaff", recordService.list());
    return "/homepage/index";
}
```

**DTO**

```
public class RecordFormHomePage implements Serializable{
int staffId;
int achievement;
int mistake;
int total;
```

**Error**

```
Message Request processing failed; nested exception is IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property [vn.sof302.trunglqph04966.record.form.RecordFormHomePage.achievement (expected type = int)]; target = [RecordFormHomePage [StaffId=111111, Achievement=0, mistake=0, total=0]], property value = [0]
```

Comment: DTO class just have getter setter

Comment: when I use DataTransformUtil to transform result to DTO, new result after transform is 0 with prop int in DTO Class

Comment: CREATE TABLE `Records` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Type` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `Reason` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Date` date NOT NULL,
  `StaffId` int(10) NOT NULL
)

Comment: I count sum each type by StaffId

Comment: Thanks. Try out the solution I proposed and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try out is assigning explicitly the types of the aliased columns

```
session.createSQLQuery("select ...")
    .addScalar("achievement", IntegerType.INSTANCE)
    .addScalar("mistake", IntegerType.INSTANCE)
    .addScalar("total", IntegerType.INSTANCE)
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(RecordFormHomePage.class))
    .list();
```

But be sure the `*Type.INSTANCE` and the class field match the database table's column type.

Comment: tks so much, it worked!! sorry for reply too late, have nice day and happy coding